# Why $f_{xy}(x_c,y_c)=f_{yx}(x_c,y_c)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Why $f_{xy}(x_c,y_c)=f_{yx}(x_c,y_c)$?

I found this used [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/readings/2nd_derivative.pdf) (in the definition of B). $x_c,y_c$ are critical points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question's been asked and answered before in several ways. [Here's my answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216214/clairauts-theorem-and-continuity-of-a-multivariate-function/216583#216583) I think you'll find it helpful.